# Maamarei Chazal on matzeivos?

Tags: death, kavod

It is common practise to include relevant pesukim from throughout tanach on a matzeivo that successfully summarises the niftar. Additionally, we know that one should be careful not to embellish the niftar's qualities as the neshomo may have to account for what is written. Therefore, can one instead use a relevant maamar chazal that may provide a more fitting definition of the niftar's personality?

Comment: Can you please source these statements? Admittedly I don’t regularly go to cemeteries, but the matzeivos I’ve seen typically only say the niftar’s name, perhaps with a couple of descriptive titles (“dear parent/sibling/spouse/etc.”), and the customary תנצבה at the bottom, with the date of petirah. I’m not sure what you refer to by adding Pesukim; I’ve just never seen this done before.

Comment: Is there any regulation about what you can put on stones at all? I'd assume a priori you can write whatever you want.

Comment: So @Double AA there is definitely not free license to say what you want - in fact the מהר"ם שי"ק in two places says that one should be particular to only feature loshon hakodesh first in Yoreh Deah 171 (https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1495&st=&pgnum=111) and in Choshen Mishpot 56 (https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1495&st=&pgnum=322) where he says clearly that the world was created in lashon hakodesh and that is the only language in hebrew letters the matzeva should be written in.

Comment: @DovSmith Neither or those are formal halakhic restrictions. As you've probably noticed if you've been to a cemetery in the USA, most people write the secular date as well. Maharam Shik was extremely anti-reform at the time and his passion about Hebrew only stones fits right in. Unless you still insist on hearing shabbos drashas in Yiddish only, you may as well move on with the rest of us. The only thing restricting what you can write is the director of the cemetery.

Comment: As far as not embellishing it writes quite clearly in the Pnei Baruch here - https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47632&st=&pgnum=418

Comment: @Double AA forgive me but I am English so I haven't been to an American beis hakvoros and I am only just looking into the inyan now for personal reasons.

Comment: I can't imagine UK cemeteries are that different

Comment: @DovSmith המקום ינחם אתכם בתוך שאר אבלי ציון וירושלים. I'm not completely understanding the premise of the question, though: if there's no problem using a posuk that summarizes the niftar's personality/accomplishments/etc., then surely there shouldn't be any issue with using a maamar Chazal in the same way, no?

Comment: Omein @Meir thank you. I was asking purely out of curiosity as I mentioned I have frequently seen pesukim used on matzeivos but never relevant chazal and I was wondering if there was a specific reason why? And it could well be they are used but since I am nogeiah b'dovor I would like to know if they can be used?

Comment: Some use presukim to spell out the person name. Also, for women some use Eishes Chayil.